# How to protect end to end services using JWT

Tags: react-native, authentication, jwt

I am trying to build mobile app using react-native backed by spring boot apis and in order to implement authentication and authorisation, i researched and found JWT is a way to go.

There are lots of implementation available for example https://medium.com/@maison.moa/using-jwt-json-web-tokens-to-authorize-users-and-protect-api-routes-3e04a1453c3e

I have few questions:

1. Most of the time you have to store JWT token on your local mobile cache to use this on subsequent requests. How safe is it to store the JWT tokens as it is.
2. Normally your create user is not JWT protected because without creating a user you can't generate any tokens. So it practically means you have exploit your user creation and it turns hacker can create any arbitrary users and generate the tokens and get access to system how to avoid that.
3. How to restrict token roles based on only the logged in user. can we bind mobile device id to generate the JWT tokens.?

Comment: 1. Depends on how safe the local storage is. 2. What do you mean by "create user"? How does your signup process lookk like? 3. A JWT contain a `roles` claim. The value of this claim is set by the service issuing the JWT. It must decide which roles to include.

Comment: Thnks for the feedback. 1/ We are talking about the local storage of the device for both android and ios. 2/ Create User doesn't has any JWT token it's open for anyone to signup. 3/ Normally for single app you more or less only one role for all end user and you may have admin role for api which you want to hide form the user app. Am i missing something here.?